# Possible to get element attribute to assign css?

Tags: css

Is it possible to speedline my code for css to grab the ID or Name and then use that in a background image?

```
<style>
.theClass{ background-image('imageof'{thisName}'.jpg'}
</style>

<div class=theClass name=dog></div>
<div class=theClass name=bird></div>
<div class=theClass name=beach></div>
```

Comment: no ..............

Comment: You could do this with javascript editing of the CSS ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to achieve this thing -

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.theClass').forEach(div => {
  div.style.backgroundImage = `imageof${div.name}.jpg`;
});
```

```html
<div class=theClass name=dog>1</div>
<div class=theClass name=bird>2</div>
<div class=theClass name=beach>3</div>
```